# Bounded function of several real variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function, absolute-value

Let $y>0$ be a positive real number

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0<x<1$

Let $a,b \in [0,x]$

I would like to know if are bounded the following functions

$$
\dfrac{1}{x}
\left|
\dfrac{b}{y^b}
-
\dfrac{a}{y^a}
\right|
$$
$$
\dfrac{1}{x}
\left|
\dfrac{1}{y^b}
-
\dfrac{1}{y^a}
\right|
$$
thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: So you want to know if for fixed $x$ and $y$ the functions $$f_1(a,b) = \dfrac{1}{x}
\left|
\dfrac{b}{y^b}
-
\dfrac{a}{y^a}
\right|$$ and $$f_2(a,b) = \dfrac{1}{x}
\left|
\dfrac{1}{y^b}
-
\dfrac{1}{y^a}
\right|$$ are bounded? Or shell $x,y$ also be arguments?

Comment: $x$,$y$ are arguments

Comment: Hence you actually want to know if the function $$f(x,y,a,b) = \dfrac{1}{x}
\left|
\dfrac{b}{y^b}
-
\dfrac{a}{y^a}
\right|\cdot 1_{(0,\infty)}(y) 1_{[0,x]^2}(a,b)$$   is bounded…

Comment: it has to be $a \leq x$ and $b \leq x$, sorry, i don't understand your syntax

Comment: The $1$ means the indicator function hence $$1_A(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in A \\ 0, & x \not\in A\end{cases}$$… so the statement above equals  $$f(x,y,a,b) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{x} \left| \dfrac{b}{y^b} - \dfrac{a}{y^a} \right|,& y\in (0,\infty), a,b\in [0,x] \\ 0, & \text{else}\end{cases}$$

Comment: ok @Gono now i understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first function take $a=0,b=x=\frac{1}{2}$ an we get

$$\sup_{a,b,x,y}\dfrac{1}{x} \left| \dfrac{b}{y^b}  - \dfrac{a}{y^a} \right| \ge \sup_{y} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} = +\infty $$

For the second take $x=b=\frac{1}{2}, a=\frac{1}{4}$ an we get:
$$\sup_{a,b,x,y}  \dfrac{1}{x} \left| \dfrac{b}{y^b}  - \dfrac{a}{y^a} \right| \ge \sup_{y} 2 \left|\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} - \frac{1}{4\sqrt[4]{y}}\right| \ge \sup_{0 < y < 1}  \left|\frac{2 - \sqrt[4]{y}}{2\sqrt{y}}\right| = +\infty$$

Comment: thanks @Gono for your answer